# Is it possible to transfer game data between two different game center accounts?

Tags: game-center

I have been wanting to transfer an existing game from my old game center account to my new one. I still have access to the old account but I am unable to find a way to transfer the data.

> Is there a possible way to do this or a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the game you want to transfer has 'other' cloud save options, such as via facebook, you can login to facebook on the old gamecenter account, then switch to the new one, re-login to facebook and re-sync the save over.

However if they don't have another 3rd party handling saves like this you're outta luck.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the game supports a 3rd party cloud save option (i.e.  Facebook login) like another answer mentions. If it doesn't have that option available then the only other way I could possibly imagine is by accessing the apps files while you have your phone plugged in to your Mac/PC.

I'm not even sure if this is possible but it's something to look into as I know I have edited apps .plist files among other things before.